# In Go+Echo's validation check, I want to display an error message even if there is a type error

Tags: go

The following processing is performed using Go + Echo + play-ground/validator.

```
if err := c.Bind(&user); err != nil {
    return err
}

err := c.Validate(user)

if err != nil {
    return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "user_form.html", err)
}
```

If there is a type error, an error will occur in `c.Bind` and it will not proceed to `c.Validate`.
Also, if an error occurs with `c.Bind`, it is not possible to identify the field that caused the error.

I would like to display type errors in `c.Bind` and mandatory checks in `c.Validate` in the same screen, but is there a good way to write them?

I looked for some other stack overflow posts but couldn't find a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this not work?
In bind error it always shows you what the error is.

See This Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type User struct {
    Id   int    `param:"id" query:"id" form:"id" json:"id" xml:"id"`
    Name string `param:"name" query:"name" form:"name" json:"name" xml:"name"`
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.POST("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        user := new(User)
        if err := c.Bind(&user); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        err := c.Validate(user)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    })
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

And send a new post request:

```bash
curl -X POST http://localhost:1323 \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"id": "1",  "name":"Joe"}'
```

error message is :

```json
{"message":"Unmarshal type error: expected=int, got=string, field=id, offset=10"}
```

error message is a JSON and tell you field id is int not a string.

Comment: When I access it with curl, I can identify the field name, but when I access it with a browser, I can't identify the field. I get an error like `{"message":"strconv.ParseInt: parsing \"aaaa\": invalid syntax"}`

Answer (score 0):

As a result of investigation, I found that `c.Bind` can identify the error field when requesting with `application/json`, but `c.Bind` cannot identify the error field when requesting with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Therefore, it may be necessary to adjust the client-side code to use echo's validation mechanism as is, or to adjust the server-side code.